# Declare an array from Core Data Attribute Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data

I have an Entity named: `Transaction` and an Attribute named: `amount`. 
I would like to declare an array from `amount` attribute that can using the summing an array sample code

`sum = array_name.reduce(0,+)`

I am trying to do this way to declare an array from Attribute

```
var amountArray = 
 (self.transactionsArray as NSArray).value(forKey: "amount") as! NSArray
sum = amountArray.reduce(0,+)
```

but it's not working and throw the error

```
Ambiguous reference to member '+'
```

Comment: That's a prefect example why you should **not** use `NSArray` in Swift. `NSArray` does not provide any type information. The compiler doesn't know if `+` means to add items (numeric) or concatenate them (string) or whether the containing type even responds to the operator `+` at all.

Comment: Something like `let sum = transactionsArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.amount }` should work, without NSArray or KVC.

Comment: thank you for your response. i tried that but it has an error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Swift 4, @MartinR's suggestion should work. If it doesn't, you should provide more information about your code, maybe specifically about the details of `Transaction`, the type of the `amount` variable, and about the exact nature of `transactionsArray`.

Assuming that `transactionsArray` is declared as the non-optional `[Transaction]` and that `amount` is one of the Core Data numeric types,

```
let sum = transactionsArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.amount }
```

...is correct. You might make it slightly more explicit by declaring the type of `sum`:

```
let sum : Double = transactionsArray.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.amount }
```

(Make sure to use the same type as `amount` here, I'm just guessing `Double`).

It's possible to get the sum with an `NSArray` and the `@sum` operator, for example

```
if let sum = (transactionsArray as NSArray).value(forKeyPath:"@sum.amount") as? Double {
    ....
}
```

The `as? Double` is needed because of the lack of type info on `NSArray` that @vadian mentioned.

Comment: Thank you a lot, i'ts worked,  i made a mistake because of wrong way to assign a double value into TextField. 